# How to load page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a page called "dual.php" using JavaScript, but it didn't work.

Here is my JavaScript code that I use:

```
btnSubmitJoin.onclick = function() {
  window.location.href = "dual.php";
}
```

I want to make it work like the HTML code that i use below:

```
<button style="--clr:#39FF14" onClick="parent.location='single.php'"><span>Single Player</span><i></i></button>
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

I have try using `window.location`, `window.parent.location`, `window.location.href`, and `window.location.replace()` but it still didn't work.
I hope someone can tell me where did I do wrong

Here is the screenshot for the details:

The JavaScript code that i use
[image]

The button

[image]

I want to make it work like this one but in JavaScript style

[image]

Comment: put `parent.location='single.php'` in the function instead ? oh, wait `btnSubmit` ... is this a form submit button you're trying to handle? you know the form will still submit, loading a new page, right

Comment: Where does `btnSubmitJoin` come from? how does it get set?

Comment: btnSubmitJoin is different button with the button that i show to u

Comment: <input id="btn-submit-join" type="submit" value="Join">

Comment: `<button style="--clr:#39FF14" onclick="this.form.action='single.php'"><span>Single Player</span><i></i></button><button style="--clr:#39FF14" onclick="this.form.action='dual.php'"><span>Dual Player</span><i></i></button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enclose your button in the form and the type is submit then the default behaviour when the button is clicked is to submit the form.

In your case when you are clicking on the button the enclosed form is getting submitted.

The solution is to prevent the default behaviour here.

```
    btnSubmitJoin.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = "dual.php";
    }
```

Comment: Why not just submit the form with the action being dual.php?

Comment: @mplungjan That can also be done. OP mentioned about the click handler hence the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is like that:

```
<button id="thisbutton" style="..." onclick="window.location.href= '/MyHomePage/dual.php'"> Go to Page </button>
```

if you want to make this over a Listener: (first delete onclick on HTML code)

javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("thisbutton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.href = '/MyHomePage/dual.php'";
});
```

this is how it is done!

Comment: The HTML code that i used  is work just fine.
Can u tell me how to turn the function that i used in my HTML code to the JavaScript style?
Because i have try several ways, but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply change the action of the form

```
<button style="--clr:#39FF14" onclick="this.form.action='single.php'"><span>Single Player</span><i></i></button>
<button style="--clr:#39FF14" onclick="this.form.action='dual.php'"><span>Dual Player</span><i></i></button>
```